# Cannot find type Microsoft.Graph.BaseGetMethodRequestBuilder`1 in module Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api

I am unable to build my UWP application whenever I add the Microsoft.Graph package to my project.
I get the following build error, as the title states:
Cannot find type Microsoft.Graph.BaseGetMethodRequestBuilder`1 in module Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll

I've tried both the latest version (1.3) and the one before it, same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by having the old OneDrive SDK installed, it doesn't play well with the new Graph SDK. Uninstalling the OneDrive SDK fixed my issue.